# How to create simple property sheet in Qt?

Tags: windows, qt

In MFC, Wizard and property sheet used to be same thing (objects), only different in style. In Qt there is QWizard and QWizardPage but I don't see how they can be used in property sheet mode. Everything else is easier in Qt but how do I create a simple property sheet which I need to show application settings.

Comment: Other than using a `QTabWidget` and perhaps binding some controls to a model using `QDataWidgetMapper`, what else do you wish to accomplish?

Comment: @KubaOber Closest I have gotten is to use `QDialog` with `QTabWidget` where I can add `Ok` button just under tab control to make a look a like of property sheet. I still will not get the `Apply` functionality but I guess I have to apply changes right there when user makes a change but changes to an edit control (like file path) will still be clumsy.

Comment: You definitely do not have to apply things right away. The *Apply* and *OK* buttons cause a copy from the UI to the data structure storing the settings. `Cancel` closes the window and simply leaves the data unchanged. When you show the property sheet, you initialize all UI from the data.

Comment: @KubaOber `Apppy`, `Cancel` is relatively easy when the tab control has one page but it gets tricky when user can multiple pages. The enable/disable logic of apply button will also need to be implemented which is readily available in MFC.

Comment: It's easy to do using a state machine. Even can be made reusable across pages, etc. :)